# Excluding specific file from Rewrite Rule. htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, file, url-rewriting

This is the simple htaccess file we're using it for a REST framework.

I just want to exclude one file `/lib/MyFile.php` from being rewritten. (All requests go through index.php and so needs BasicAuth)

```
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(static_files/.*)$
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(lib/MyFile.php)$ // this is not working
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

The complete URL of the file is `http://domain.com/lib/MyFile.php`

Comment: There is no need for a group. Try: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/lib/MyFile\.php  [NC]`

Comment: No dice! Tried this already.

Comment: If you are talking about not applying the rewrite rule to any incoming URL that holds the string `lib/MyFile.php`, using mod_rewrite directives inside an .htaccess file, that's the correct syntax and there is NO other way to do it. So, the problem is not with that particular line, but it is impossible to guess from the information you provide what's the problem. It is no even clear if the Rewrite Engine is on. Too much guesswork.

Comment: I understand. But anyways. Pls post your soln as answer. I will accept it.

Comment: Really appreciate your intention, but you said you have tried the same syntax unsuccessfully, which means my comment is not a solution to your problem. Update your question with more information, the whole .htaccess file for example, to try to really solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks. you are awesome! However, thats all my htaccess file. Just RewriteEngine on on top. You can just leave the answer. If would just upvote. Since thats a relevant info.